# Use default values for new properties in Realm migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My Realm data model has a `User` class and I added a new property to it:

```
dynamic var useImages: Bool = true
```

I didn't do anything in the migration block:

```
if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
}
```

Now I expected that after the migration each old `User` object would have a new `useImages` property **already set to `true`** (the default value). But the `useImages` property is set to `false` after the migration.

Is that supposed to happen?

If so, is there an easy way to have Realm use the default values for new properties when migrating databases? Or do I have to do it in the migration block for every new property one by one:

```
newObject!["useImages"] = true
```

That seems silly. Is there a better way?

Comment: It should be true, still, you can try workaround like `Int` = 0/1, or change to sth like `notUseImage`

Comment: @Tj3n Yes, for now I'm working around it in various ways... but I don't understand why it's not using the default value if it should, like I suspected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [an unfixed bug](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1793), and as you've discovered you have to manually loop over the objects and set the default value in the migration.

Oddly this is currently documented in the Objective-C docs on migrations, but not the Swift docs.

Comment: Ah, I thought I was doing something wrong. Alright then, I guess I'll have to live with that for now. Thanks!